# How can i create an array of objects with the object entries?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I want to create an array of objects from the this.props.data, trying to do that i can't make the map put the key values which are normally generated by the object.entries.

I have a screenshot with the code, and some console logs and the results they show instead of {_key:"0"}, i want it to be {numberOfElements:"12"}.
Thanks.

This is the problematic part of the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class DataTable extends Component{
  render(){
    const data= Object.entries(this.props.data).map((_key,_value)=>({
      _key:String(_value)
    }));
    console.log(data)
    console.log(Object.entried(this.props.data))
    return <div></div>
  }

}
```

[image]

**Console Output :**

[image: e]

Comment: `.map((_key, _value) => ( { [_key]: _value } ))` should do the trick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ok so if you want an array of objects, each one representing one key/value pair of your original object, this will do the trick for you:

```js
original = {
 x : 2,
 y : 3,
}

mapped = Object.entries(original).map(([_key, _value]) => ({[_key]: String(_value)}));

console.log(mapped);
```

if you need a new object with same key/values, but having the values mapped (for example by `String()`), then this should work for you:

```js
original = {
  x: 2,
  y: 3,
};

mapped = Object.entries(original)
         .reduce((obj, [_key, _value]) => 
           Object.assign(obj, { [_key]: String(_value) }),
           {});

console.log(mapped);
```

and if you need the mapped object but inside an array, well, put it inside an array:

```js
original = {
  x: 2,
  y: 3,
}

mappedInArray = [
  Object.entries(original).reduce((obj, [_key, _value]) => 
    Object.assign(obj, { [_key]: String(_value) }), {})];

console.log(mappedInArray);
```

---

also, generally speaking, note that you are doing this:

```js
Object.entries(obj).map((_key, _value) => ...);
```

which is wrong, because entries is a list of pairs (arrays of length two, the first item being the key, the second item being the value), which when mapped, will go to your `_key` parameter, and hence your `_value` parameter would simply be the index of that key-value pair in the array of entries. i.e. you will get:

```
_key = [<first-key>, <first-value>]; _value = 0;
_key = [<second-key>, <second-value>]; _value = 1;
...
```

you should instead write that like this:

```js
Object.entries(obj).map(([_key, _value]) => ...);
```

Comment: i tried this on https://jsfiddle.net/exprd5o7/2/ and it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @tahtoh its because in your fiddle you are feeding an array of objects into the function, not an object. [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x75zqkfo/) is the corrected version of your fiddle, you can also run the snippet embedded in the answer itself.

Comment: yes it does work like you said  but it generates it like 0: {numberofElements: "14"}
1: {test: "5"} instead of 0: {numberofElements: "14",test: "5"}

Comment: because my input needs to be an array of objects @Eugene

Comment: @tahtoh I am still not 100% certain of what is the thing you need, but I updated the answer and I suspect it covers what you are looking for now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be composing an Object like this:

```
let object = {}; object[_key] = String(_value); return object;
```

Comment: A simpler way would be `return { [_key]: String(_value) }`. Not sure why `String(...)` is used though